# JAVA Library for charts- JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

first of all: I did read all the other similar questions and i have taken a look at JFreeChart, which seems to be the weapon of choice for producing charts for a Java desktop app. It would actually suit my needs too, but the project seems to be dead.The forums are down, last update was in 2009.

Question is, is there any other library comparable to JFreeChart, or should i use JFreeChart anyway, because it´s awesome and i will never need support from the -now dead- official forums ?

Your thoughts on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are your requirements for your charting library?  What is the  main place the charts will be viewed?  In app?  On the web?  As an exported graphic?

Comment: Nothing exotic. It´s an app that draws data from a DB, does  "SELECT COUNT"s on several entity properties, compares them to hardcoded numerical limits and displays the results as a function over time.The charts should be zoomable, because the needed time-stretch (x-axis) will vary from 4 years to a couple of months and it would be very nice if i could overlay 3 or 4 graphs with different y-axis definitions (different functions over the same time-stretch). I´m not a native english seaker, i hope i make myself sufficiently understood :)

Comment: Where do the charts display, though?  On a website?  Exported as PDFs, ect?

Comment: On the main window of the application, a plain java desktop application. Export to PDF should definitely be an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you take another look at JFreeChart. It is very comprehensive and if you have problems I'm sure you'll find quick answers to them here on SO.

This [JFreeChart FAQ](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ13) lists alternatives but they are not as powerful.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp). It's actively developed, and with the recent 2.0.0 release, it has many features of a mature charting library. The jar is on ~86 KB and it has no dependencies. It's licensed under Apache 2.0 and is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart). Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the project.

Comment: Just looked over the examples and decided to give XChart a try in my next project. On first look, it doesn´t look as customizable as JFreechart, BUT: the code examples are very brief and self-explanatory. Thanks for sharing, herrtim.

Comment: With the StyleMananger you can customize almost anything visually on the chart. See [LineChart03](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/blob/develop/xchart-demo/src/main/java/com/xeiam/xchart/demo/charts/line/LineChart03.java) .You could also set a Theme and even create your own. See [ThemeChart02](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/blob/develop/xchart-demo/src/main/java/com/xeiam/xchart/demo/charts/line/LineChart03.java).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?

And some third party Java client libraries for the same.

http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/

http://code.google.com/p/javagooglechart/

Comment: One downside is that charts4j and google charts api require you to be online because they use google servers to draw the charts.

Comment: Yeah :( that's a major downside.

Answer (score 0):

I used for test purpose some job with [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)
It's pretty active as a project, and quite complete, but it depends on what you'll need to display.

Oh and I used also ILOG (Now IBM) JViews Charts&Diagrammer to display a plane dashboard. With good coding you can achieve nice performance. But if I remember it's far from free ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/website/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_features.html?header=project&target=ireport)? Very reliable and versatile. It provides a WYSIWYG environment
to design reports and Graphs. It is a simple and high level interface that sits on top of JasperReports and JFreeChart that takes care of the "dirty work".