# How to show data graphically in Java?

Tags: java, graph

I am developing an application in Java. I got a requirement to show data in graphical form.
In ASP.NET we can use Chart Controls to show data graphically. Likewise, how can we show the data graphically in Java. I am using Eclipse Ganymede. How to show data graphically from a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many such libraries, some of them listed in various SO posts such as [JAVA Library for charts- JFreeChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193953/java-library-for-charts-jfreechart).

I personally used [Gral](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/) to draw some simple plots, it was perfect for my purposes. There are some examples of the look and feel [on their web site](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/wiki/Gallery).

Answer (score 1):

There are several free java apis available to show data graphically in the form of charts like: For Java standalone application you can use jFreeChart

```
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html
```

for java web application you can use highcharts(for non-comercial use)

```
http://www.highcharts.com/
```